# Unable to automatically click a button using nodejs and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

When I load index.html on port 3000 and when I click on play button, all the messages are sent properly, but the `('#pause').click()` is not being executed because the audio does not pause.

index.html code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="new.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" id="play" name="play" value="play">PLAY</button>
  <button onclick="pauseAd()" type="button" name="pause" value="pause">PAUSE</button>
  </br>
  <audio controls id="song">
    <source src="Lyrics to Swallowed in the Sea - Coldplay.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>

  <div id="messages"></div>

  <script>
    var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

    $(function() {
      $('#play').bind('click', function() {
        alert("User clicked on play");
        playAd();
        socket.emit('msg', {
          sent: 1
        });
        return false;
      });
    });


    socket.on('msg-received', function(data) {
      if (data.value == 1) {
        $('#pause').click();
        $('#messages').append('<p>message received' + data.value + '</p>')
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Server code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static('./Public'));


app.set('views', __dirname + '/tpl');
app.set('view engine', "jade");
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("new");
});


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

  console.log("user connected");
  socket.on('msg', function(data) {
    console.log("message received", data);

    socket.emit('msg-received', {
      value: 1
    });
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: The "$(#pause)" is looking for an ID with the value pause. Try adding id="pause" to your button =)

Answer (score 1):

The `$('#pause')` is JQuery's selector for the element with the id attribute of `pause`. You currently don't have an element with the id attribute of `pause`, so `$('#pause')` currently returns nothing.

To fix your problem, all you need to do is add the attribute `id='pause'` to your pause button, which becomes:

`<button id='pause' onclick="pauseAd()" type="button" name="pause" value="pause">PAUSE</button>`

This will have JQuery select the button when you select the elements with the id of `pause`

Hope this helped and if you need further clarification let me know.

Comment: Looks good - verified with [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/232nmosF2VJFuwhif2yu?p=preview)